# ERROR ON QUERYING ORACLE DB

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using oracle 10g and I wrote a create table query like this -

```
String UserTable="CREATE TABLE UserDetail ( \n" +
               "        idNo INT(64) NOT NULL , \n" +
               "        name VARCHAR(50),\n" +
               "        email VARCHAR(50),  \n" +
               "        state VARCHAR(50),\n"+
               "       country VARCHAR(50),\n" +                    
               "        CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY ('idNo')"
                   + ");";


          // Connection con2=DriverManager.getConnection(DbAddress,"vivek","123456");
           PreparedStatement st2=conn.prepareStatement(UserTable);
           st2.executeUpdate();
           conn.close();
```

but it gives following exception-

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

on syssout it the query becomes this -

```
CREATE TABLE UserDetail ( 
    idNo INT(64) NOT NULL , 
    name VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50),  
    state VARCHAR(50),
   country VARCHAR(50),
   CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY (idNo)
```

);

please help.

Comment: SYSOUT your UserTable variable above PreparedStatement and run that query in Oracle. you will see what's go wrong.

Comment: `'idNo'` is a string literal `idNo` would be a valid identifier to be used in a constraint definition.

Comment: Try getting rid of the quotes in the PK constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh I got the solution- I was using Int instead of Number and it was not supported. the query should be-

```
"CREATE TABLE UserDetail ( \n" +
           "        idNo NUMBER NOT NULL , \n" +
           "        name VARCHAR(50),\n" +
           "        email VARCHAR(50),  \n" +
           "        state VARCHAR(50),\n"+
           "       country VARCHAR(50),\n" +                    
           "        CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY ('idNo')"
               + ");";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below line

```
 CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY ('idNo')
```

Use the below line in your code instead

```
 CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY (idNo)
```

Comment: single line answer ? this could be comment rather . try to provide some explanation